# Youtube api v3 - Get all of videos from the chanel

Tags: android, youtube-api

I got the problem when trying to get all of videos from a chanel.
Here is the chanel:
http://www.youtube.com/channel/UC0vrmjhkmbCxYUGl8KNFxMA
I try to get Playlist with my API key but it returned an empty array:
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet&channelId=UC0vrmjhkmbCxYUGl8KNFxMA&key=
Please help me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The channelId parameter does not specify a channel to return videos for. Think of it as a "filter" to only show playlists from a specific channel.

Instead, do this:

1. Make a `channel.list()` API call with your channel ID and the `part=contentDetails`. Save the value under `items[0][contentDetails][relatedPlaylists][uploads]`. Example:

   > GET
   >   https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&id=UC0vrmjhkmbCxYUGl8KNFxMA&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
2. Make a `playlistItems.list()` API call with the value retrieved in the ID field. In your specific case, this is `UU0vrmjhkmbCxYUGl8KNFxMA`. The API call is:

   > GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=UU0vrmjhkmbCxYUGl8KNFxMA&key={YOUR_API_KEY}